# Binning with qcut, cant raise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, binning

I have a dataset with lots of duplicate values. Still, I want to bin the dataset! As I understood, there are two possibilities, to drop duplicate values (which makes perfectly sense me) and 'raise' (raise would mean to keep them and count them within the bin?).
But for some reason, if I set `duplicates='raise`' then I get the following error `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.        , 14.09240414, 31.        , 31.        , 31.        ,`
31.        ]).

When I'm using the 'drop' attribute, my bins get very uneven, the only workaround I found so far, is to rank each value. Would you have any ideas?

Also, is there a possibility to count the dropped values and display them in a separate bin?

Best,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

It's because 'raise' means raise an error; not include the 0's.   Facing the same thing myself.

Here's the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html